# Looking for an example of a local homomorphism between regular and CM rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I am looking for a concrete example of a regular local ring $(R,m)$,
a Cohen-Macaulay local ring $(S,n)$ which is not Gorenstein, and a local homomorphism $(R,m) \to (S,n)$ which is **not** flat.

Comment: Take $R=k[[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]]$, $k$ any field. Take $S=k[[t^3,t^2u, tu^2,u^3]]$ with the map $x_1\mapsto t^3, x_2\mapsto t^2u$ etc.

Comment: Also, one can take $R = k[[x,y]]$, where $k$ is a field, and $S = k[[x,y]]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$.